# String formatting with class variable names lookup in PHP

Tags: php, class

I'm simply trying to make a string look up its class properties dynamically.

I have a class that's used by a Factory to create basic objects of a certain type. Inside this class, I have a `getMessage` function which simply returns whatever was passed in the constructor as the message:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public function __construct( $message )
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

But a new requirement just came in. There's another function `doCheck` which populates that class' property `private $check_data` with a list of dynamic (names) variables. These variables' names - I don't know, but they're used by the message to build itself, so, going from a constructor like `new BaseClass( 'Some message.' )` to `new BaseClass('#number_of_days have passed!')` where `#number_of_days` performs a look up inside the class to look for that property and put it inside the string.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: show full class where doCheck method

Comment: @Aleksandr Hi! Not sure how that'd help. I'm just trying to make a string look for class properties. The example provided here is enough and if I were to post the full class, I'd have so much stuff that's completely useless for the scope of the question.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you need something like this? [link](https://pastebin.com/htDSEeq8)

Comment: @Aleksandr Correct! I'm just trying to find out whether or not I can write this without `preg_match` and if there's an automatic mechanism to doing all this.

Comment: There is no automatic. Another example [link](https://pastebin.com/cJQx0gMG)

Comment: An alternative is [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).